# Cannot apply migrations to Database: because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I am a beginner in this. I am working on this `ASP.NET Core MVC` project where I have two tables: `Locations` and `History`. I had created the two tables using `Code-First Approach` from `Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager Console`. Due to some reasons, I had to drop the two tables. I deleted the two `Models`: `Locations` and `History`. Then I created a new `Migration`, following which I updated the database. On checking the Database from `SQL Server Management Studio`, I see that the tables are not there.

Now, I want to create the same two tables with some changes. When I am trying to add the tables to the database using `Code-First Approach` where I am typing the command `update-database` in the `NuGet Package Manager Console`, I get the following error:

> Error Number:3701,State:5,Class:11
>   Cannot drop the table 'History', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

However on checking in the database, I am not seeing the table. I even checked for the table by executing the `select * from History` query which gives results in

> Invalid object name 'History'.

I feel that there is a mismatch between the Database and my Project. What to do?

Comment: Is this EF6 or EF Core? Are you doing an `add-migration` or using auto migrations. Sounds like things might be out of sync and you need to do a [reset](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate).

Comment: I second what @SteveGreene said.  You need to take action on your migrations to sync them up to the current model.  add-migration and then Update-Database to sync or enable automatic migrations and run the Update-Database command.

Comment: I followed what @SteveGreene said and referred to the link provided by him. I deleted tables, models, migrations and recreated them. Now it's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveGreene Could you post an answer so that I can mark it as correct. This will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: [Rick's link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate) is the solution to these kind of issues. The only table you should need to delete is __MigrationHistory and you should not need to recreate your models either. Glad it worked.